# Views are shown modally instead of normal

Tags: swift, swift5

I linked the Views with seague and then show. It did not click on modally. Why does it still show them like that instead of Fullscreen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `fullScreen`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
}
```

Comment: I dont know why but this doesnt work. I wrote that in every ...Controller.swift file. The first screen in Fullscreen without adding your code. The others are shown modally even with adding your code.

Comment: I solved it. I clicked on Fullscreen on the property inspector. Under Transition Style. It was automatic before.